# How to find duplicate element(1-10) in an array using console Application

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

How can I find duplicate element(1-10) in an array using console Application?

```
class program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {              
        int[] array = { 10, 5, 8, 64, 25, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10};

        int count = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < array.Length; j++)
            {

                if(array[i] == array[j])
                    count = count + 1;

            }

            Console.WriteLine("\t\n " + array[i] + "occurs" + count);  
            Console.ReadKey();
         }
    }
}
```

The output is correct, but the loop is repeating.

Comment: We can't debug your code if you don't show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, is seems like your loop is printing out how many duplicates each number has for each place in the array, instead of once for each unique digit.

One simple solution would be to create [`List<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) to keep track of the numbers you already checked for duplicates. The second `for` loop and `Console.WriteLine` part of the code will only execute if the number does not already exist in the List.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 10, 5, 8, 64, 25, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10};

    List<int> doneNumbers = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if(!doneNumbers.Contains(array[i]))
        {
            int currentNumber = array[i];
            int count = 0;

            for (int j = i; j < array.Length; j++)
            {

                if(currentNumber == array[j])
                {
                    count++;
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine("\t\n " + currentNumber + " occurs " + count + " times");
            doneNumbers.Add(currentNumber);
        }

     }
}
```

Other things you also need to fix:

- `int count = 0` needs to be moved to inside the first for loop so that it resets for each element in the array.
- `int count` should start from 0 instead of 1.
- You do not need `Console.ReadKey();`.
- Instead of constantly writing `array[i]`, you should store that value in a variable and just reference that. I called `currentNumber`.